# mongo db , node express , extract an element from output returned by mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

for first block of code , console.log("ff : "+ff) prints exactly like this :

> ff : { _id : sd845y3hishofiuwhei , fullname : 'sachin' }

```
console.log("ff JSON : "+JSON.stringify(ff)); // this line prints like below :
```

> ff JSON : [{"_id":"sd845y3hishofiuwhei" , "fullname" : "sachin" }]

how can i get that "sachin" separately in a separate variable ?

```
var fullname=SampleModel.find({uname:req.session.uname},{fullname : true},function(err,ff){
    if(!err){
        console.log("ff : "+ff);
        console.log("ff JSON  : "+JSON.stringify(ff));
        return ff;
    }else { 
        return null;
    }
});
```

the below block of code is giving error like "invalid object id " . what can be the problem ?

```
var ret= AnotherModel.find({_id : { $nin : ["1","2"] } }, function(err,details){
    if(!err) {
        res.send(details);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error : "+err);
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

i am implementing textarea like this

```
<textarea id="myarea" cols="100" rows="20"   ></textarea>
```

output box is changing its height when i change rows , but that cols , when i change "cols" , its width not changing . the output box also has small width , i check in both chrome and mozilla. Whats the solution ?
Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you use mongoose and not only mongodb driver.

In the first block of code, the ff value isn't a string but an array of objects.

You can access "sachin" variable just doing something like : `var fullname = ff[0].fullname;`
Of course, it's best to iterate through the array but you get the idea.

If you want only one object to be retrieved, you should use "findOne" function instead and then you would be able to access "sachin" like this : `var fullname = ff.fullname;`

For the second question, you should use Query system. Queries are delayed requests that you can chain and tune more finely. To delay your query, just ommit the callback function : `var query = Model.find({});`

Then, add the filter you want, in your case : `query.where('_id').nin(['1', '2']);`

Finally, execute it :

```
query.exec(function (err, docs) {
    // called when the `query.complete` or `query.error` are called
    // internally
});
```

Informations about [finding docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/finding-documents.html) and about [queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/query.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer, can anyone tell me solution for the text area problem i have mention at the end ?

Comment: Model.findById("idstring")
Model.find({_id : "idstring"})

Both of the above are giving error "INVALID OBJECT ID " , only for id i am getting error , for others like {uname : "username"} , i am getting solution . So, i think i am passing id in the wrong format ,  what is the correct format in which i can give _id as a parameter .

Comment: Have you declared _id as an Schema.ObjectId in your item Schema ? Please post your schema declaration code.

Comment: i didnt declare _id at all. When i insert any data, it creates new _id . Anyway , please tell me this one . I have a collection with unique entries username , _id where _id is automatically created by mongo. How should i refer this particular user in another collection with better performance ? i mean, whether referrng by username or _id  or a normal "id" that we assign it some value ? what is the best way ?

Comment: my schema :

var user = new Schema({
    uname : { type : String , required:true ,unique:true},
    pwd : {type : String , required:true},
});

now, i tried addng this field _id : {type : ObjectId} which resulted  in an error saying "Reference Errror : ObjectId is not defined "

Comment: i mentioned my schema in the above comment

Comment: i added _id : { type :Schema.ObjectId } , that doesnot give anyerror ,  but when i am using model.find({_id : "idstring"}) , i am still getting error "invalid object id " . i can simply use a normal id with increment but i read that ,that the objectIds are better for performance in mongodb, so thats y still trying to use that _id

Comment: Ok, the problem here is that you pass a string as objectId when you call the find metthod. You should do it this way : 

    `var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,`
        `id = new ObjectId('the id string');`

    `model.find({_id: id});`

Comment: That's Types.ObjectId taht you must import, not SchemaObjectId, sorry for the mistake.
    
    `var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;`